# FlipClock: How do you set EST time

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, flipclock

I am using `flipclock`, I would like to set an EST time on it.
How do I able to do it?, I have `moment.js` in placed and I can use it to get the current Eastern Time. But the problem is, I do not know what to pass on the method  `setTime()` of `flipclock` object.

Answer (score 1):

The flipclock `setTime` method takes a `time`, and as per the [api reference](http://flipclockjs.com/api), this is:

> **time**
>
> *(int) The current time (in seconds)*

So, to get the current time in seconds, you can take your `Date` object and do `getTime() / 1000`

```
var currentTimeInSeconds = new Date().getTime() / 1000; // or use your Momentjs date
```

And pass that to your flipclock:

`flipclock.setTime(currentTimeInSeconds)`